# Why is the same WordPress function working on one site and not on another?

Tags: wordpress

OK, I have a WordPress site that uses a custom theme.

This theme includes a shortcode that is intended to be used in a text widget in the sidebar, and this shortcode displays the most recent posts. It defaults to the last three, but you can change this using a parameter if you want.

This is the function that processes the shortcode:

```
function wp_widget_recent_posts( $atts ){

  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'count' => 3,
  ), $atts ));

  ob_start();
    $arg = array(
      'post_type'         => 'post',
      'post_status'     => 'publish',
      'order'           => 'DESC',
      'orderby'         => 'date',
      'posts_per_page'  => $atts['count'],
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($arg);
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/posts-loop-item' ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query();

  $result = ob_get_clean();
  return $result;

}
add_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'wp_widget_recent_posts' );
```

This all works fine on my site.

However, I have a friend who is using the same theme (and running the same version of WordPress on the same version of PHP), and on his site, when you ask for the most recent three posts, it actually shows six. (There are only seven posts on his site right now.)

After some digging, I found that:

1. If you ask for four posts, it shows seven.
2. If you ask for three posts, it shows six.
3. If you ask for two posts, it shows five.
4. If you ask for one post, it shows four.
5. If you ask for zero posts, it still shows six.

It's as though it's adding three to the parameter you pass to the function.

It should be noted that the above function is identical on both sites.

Digging further, I found that this is the MySQL call generated by the above function:

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3

I've never seen SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS before, but since this is generated by the core WordPress code (because there is no function called WP_Query within the theme code), I'm assuming it's all correct.

The results of what I did next surprised me.

I wanted to make a small change to the above function, purely to make sure that the latest version of the function was being used. (I had a suspicion that changes I was making to the theme's functions.php file were being ignored.)

I therefore changed the Order parameter from DESC to ASC.

When I did this and refreshed the page, only three posts were displayed in the sidebar, as expected.

The MySQL call for this was as follows:

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 3

I'm now lost - I have absolutely no idea why:

1. This function works on my site (and on a few other sites where I've helped the site owner set up this same WordPress theme.
2. Why it doesn't work on my friend's site with posts in descending order, but does work with posts in ascending order.
3. Why it appears to take the number of posts requested in the shortcode parameter and add three to it.

Anybody got any pointers on where to look next?

Comment: Does your friend have any caching plugins installed? Or is using Varnish caching or CloudFlare caching? Does the problem still happen if you disable all of the other plugins on her site?

Comment: I don't see any caching plug-ins. There were a couple I'd never seen before that I don't believe are necessary, so I deactivated those, but the problem is still occurring. The only plug-ins that are now active are ones that I have on my own site.

And as far as I can tell, it's not using a caching service such as CloudFlare.

Comment: I feel like your code is fine, and the problem has to do with some dumb little something in an unrelated part of the site. But that's just my guess. I would copy the site to a staging site, and then start stripping stuff away: deactivate plugins, revert to the default WordPress theme theme, remove mu-plugins, test the site on the same server your site is on, revert the htaccess file to the default, revert the permalinks, reinstall WordPress. etc. If you keep making the site look more like vanilla WordPress, eventually you should come across whatever it is that is causing the problem.

Comment: I think you're right.

I re-uploaded the theme, so it's identical to my site, and I re-installed WordPress, but I still have the same issues.

I also found a problem in the footer - it contains a menu, and the items are an unordered list that should be styled to be inline, but on my friend's site, the menu items are stacked, rather than being on a single line.

I was wondering was whether the hosting company might make a difference - my site is on HostGator, whereas my friend's is on Blue Host.

Maybe there are differences in server set-up or Mod Security rules?

Comment: Well, I wiped my friend's site clean and rebuilt it from scratch, using the theme file and plug-ins from my own site, which I know is working as it should, and yet the two problems on my friend's site remain - the sidebar is still showing more than the latest three posts, and the menu items in the footer are still stacked rather than being on the one line.

I really have no idea what's going on, and have to assume it's a difference in hosting set-up at this stage.